# Using Corona SDK's scripts in android

Tags: android, coronasdk

I'm new in developing .lua plugins. I wonder if it's possible to integrate scripts written in LUA (Corona SDK) into our application. And if it's possible can you share the link to be used as tutorial, because I couldn't find any

Comment: you want to integrate .lua files in your Corona app or Corona .lua files into a native app?

Comment: are you a Corona Enterprise subscriber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using Corona Enterprise.

Corona Enterprise makes Corona run as a library for your application, so Corona Enterprise do exactly what you want.

Otherwise, no, you cannot do it.